# Facebook app in development test users pending status super delayed notifications for invite

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I believe my question is extremely simple and very basic but I am totally confused I am working on an app that uses Facebook login and the app is currently in development mode with Facebook and I am trying to add some early test users some of these test users have been waiting one full day to receive some sort of notification from Facebook to enable them to join the testing phase of mine in development application

How long does it usually take to have a new test user added to a Facebook app in development mode? Should it be taking hours and hours and days or should it be instantaneous?

Comment: The notification asking them to become a tester should arrive almost instantly. They need to have their account verified/registered in the developer section in the first place though, otherwise they can’t become testers, and therefor will not receive this notification either.

Comment: Facebook indicated the same ... it should be instantly... Where do users have their account verified/registered "in the developer section" ?

Comment: Don’t remember, way too long ago I did that. Try sending them to the developer section and see what happens … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps#register

Comment: No prob thx for ur response